# Subset of array by evaluating element

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am trying to obtain a series of subsets from an array in javascript using underscore. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
Original array: [1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1]
Expected result: [1,1,1] [2,2,2] [0,0,0] [1,1,1]
```

When I use the filter method from underscore, I get three arrays: `[1,1,1,1,1,1] [2,2,2] [0,0,0];` I would like that the last array of 1's would not mix.

What I've tried:

```
_.filter(array, function(e){
     return e === 1;
})
```

The criteria to split the original array is that the consecutive equal numbers must form a new array, but if the number appears later in the original array, that consecutive equal number must form a *new* array.

Is there a way to do this using underscore or should it be done with loops?

Thanks

Comment: What are your rules for splitting up the array? groups of three in the order they originally appear? Something else?

Comment: can jquery be part of a solution ?

Comment: jquery is often part of the problem :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is something specific in underscrore.js to do this, but I'm sure it could be done in underscore syntax. However, you could do something like this in POJS.

Javascript

```
var testArray = [NaN, NaN, NaN, undefined, undefined, undefined, null, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];

function is(x, y) {
    if (x === y) {
        if (x === 0) {
            return 1 / x === 1 / y;
        }

        return true;
    }

    var x1 = x,
        y1 = y;

    return x !== x1 && y !== y1;
}

function arraySplitToGroups(array) {
    var length = array.length,
        i = 0,
        newArray = [],
        subArray = [],
        current,
        last;

    while (i < length) {
        current = array[i];

        if (!is(last, current)) {
            if (subArray.length) {
                newArray.push(subArray);
            }

            subArray = [];
        }

        subArray.push(current);
        last = current;
        i += 1;
    }

    if (subArray.length) {
        newArray.push(subArray);
    }

    return newArray;
}

console.log(arraySplitToGroups(testArray));
```

Output

```
[ [NaN, NaN, NaN], [undefined, undefined, undefined], [null, null, null], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1] ]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KU5Re/)

**UPDATE**: Just as a pure interest thing, I took all the answers that were currently on the page a created a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/split-array-to-groups) for them.

Answer (score 1):

A plain old Javascript solution:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPUTq/2/)

```
var original = [1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1];

var newArr = [], currentValue = null, currentArr;

if(original.length > 0){
    for(var i=0; i<original.length; i++){
        if(currentValue == null){
            currentValue = original[i];
            currentArr = [currentValue];
        } else {
            if(currentValue == original[i]){
                currentArr.push(currentValue);
            } else {
                newArr.push(currentArr);
                currentArr = [original[i]];
            }
        }
        currentValue = original[i];
    }
    newArr.push(currentArr);
}
```

Outputs:

```
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Why do you need `if(original.length > 0){` ?

Comment: Without that, if original is empty then the result will be `[null]`. Whereas using the length check, the result will be `[]` if original was empty.

Comment: How about something like this (may never occur in the OPs situation but can't be sure)? [undefined,undefined, undefined, null, null, null, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: @Xotic750 based on what OP said about the criteria, I think it will only contain numbers so no `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: MrCode as you can see the if is not required: [with if](http://jsfiddle.net/gGRk5/) vs [without if](http://jsfiddle.net/gGRk5/1)

Comment: @jantimon that isn't with and without if, what you have there is my version with if, your version without if - they aren't the same.

Comment: @MrCode oh sry now I get it. It's because your `newArr.push` in the end.

Comment: Yes, I can see a way of removing the if and moving the final push elsewhere inside a nested if, but I'll just leave it as is. As always in programming there are infinite ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got something quite straight forward and short:

```
function groupValues(arr) {
    var o=[];
    var temp=0;
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if (i<=0 || arr[i]!==arr[i-1]) {
            if (i>0) {
                ++temp;
            }
            o[temp]=[];
        }
        o[temp].push(arr[i]);
    }
    return o;
}
```

You may take a look at this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dgsqa/2/).

Comment: Where is the declaration of `v`?

Comment: @Xotic750 Oops, missed that when "functionalizing" the script, updated. Thanks

Comment: Not so shabby for someone that wanted to make a jquery solution ;)

Comment: @Xotic750 I think that an unwanted jQuery solution is a *bad* solution. On SO I'm the first to advise new users not to spam jQuery solutions if it isn't tagged in the OP so I prefer asking first :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple function like this:

```
function splitArray(original) {
    var newArr = [], currentValue, currentArr;

    for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
       if (i === 0 || currentValue !== original[i]) {
         currentArr = [];
         newArr.push(currentArr);
       }
       currentArr.push(currentValue = original[i]);
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

See the working <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gGRk5/1/)</kbd>

It is based on the example of MrCode but with less code.

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner that would do you the job would be:

```
var input = [1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1]; 
var output = (input.join(',')+',').match(/(\d*,)\1+/g).map(function(str){return str.replace(/,$/,'').split(',').map(Number);})
```

Basically what it does:

```
  (input.join(',') + ',') // concatenate all numbers with a ',', and add a trailing comma to help the matching
     .match(/(\d*,)\1+/g) // match groups of numbers of the same type with comma ( "1,1,2,"  > ["1,1", "2,"] ). The * is to support null/undefined values in the original array
     .map(                // replace every match (only works in modern browsers, but you can replace it with _.map )
           function() {
              return str.replace(/,$/, '')  // remove trailing ', '
                        .split(',')         // and split the string by , "1,1,1" > [1,1,1]
                        .map(Number)        // map everything back to Number (converts undefined / null values to 0 as a sideeffect, but keeps them as a group
           }
      );
```

If you don't want to rely on the availabilty of [`map` provided by only modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can use underscore map like this:

```
var input = [1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1]; 
var output = _.map((input.join(',')+',').match(/(\d*,)\1+/g), function(str){ return _.map(str.replace(/,$/,'').split(','), Number);});
```

**Bware**

As it is visible in the [jsperf analysis](http://jsperf.com/split-array-to-groups) made by **Xotic750**, this is the least performant solution. I just listed it as an alternative, maybe shortest way.

Comment: Doesn't appear to give the same output as the OP requested: `["1,1,1,", "2,2,2,", "0,0,0,", "1,1,1,"] `

Comment: Yes I've realized that I return strings, so I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3];
var result = [];
var temp = [];
_.each(original,function(num,index){
     temp.push(num);
     if(original[index+1] != 'undefined' && num != original[index+1])
    {
        result.push(temp);
        temp = [];
   }
});
console.log(result);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2AChG/